# How to set datetimepicker to localtime when posting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, datetimepicker

I have a problem when i am posting a editform with a datetime value in it. I have a script that sets the localdatetime with getTimeZonOffset. The first time when i want the utc time from the database to be displayed in localtime it works. The problem is when i want to edit the form with a datetimepicker. The new value gets stored in the database and every time the user hits the submit button it adds the localtime again.

How can i do to avoid this?

```
  $(function () {
    // Determine timezone offset in milliseconds
 var d = new Date();
 var offsetms = d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;

    $('.UTCTime input').each(function () {
        try
        {     
            var text = $(this).val();
            var n = new Date(text);
            n = new Date(n.valueOf() - offsetms);

            var curr_date = n.getDate();
            var curr_month = n.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
            var curr_year = n.getFullYear();
            var curr_hour = n.getHours();
            var curr_minutes = n.getMinutes();

            $(this).val(curr_year + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_date + " " + curr_hour + ":" + curr_minutes);

        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.warn("Error converting time", ex);
        }
    });
});

 $(function () {
$(".datetimepicker input").datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    showTime: true,
});
});

 <div class="span3 value UTCTime datetimepicker">
```

Comment: Did you get an answer yet?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your script will override any value already saved when you edit it

You need to add some kind of check when setting the datetime value so you dont override it

```
if( !$(this).val() ) {
      $(this).val(curr_year + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_date + " " + curr_hour + ":" + curr_minutes);
}
```

You might have to change the if-condition if you have some other default value

Comment: I don´t think that will work for me. I found a solution with a function thats sets the date value to utc again before the post is being made. It looks exactly the same as the function above with the exception of  n = new Date(n.valueOf() + offsetms); Idon´t think this is the best solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Make unique index in your database for userid and timezone, that means that the current time zone can not be re entered again for the same user it can be updated.

If you have mysql db then use insert into table on duplicate key update....

Hope this will give you the correct idea.

Comment: Do i really have to change the database. Cant i somehow just add getTimezoneOffset when i use my datetimepicker.

Comment: Well if you don't want to get duplicates in your database, and to avoid writting a lot of queries then use this. Other ways you can write aditional queries to check wheater this user has set his own time zone or not, and if he'd set then rewrite it. But you can get localTimeZone (users time zone) only by using Javascript.